# Create new array from two array in with i will count the number of occurence some values in php

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays

The first array:

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 291 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 292 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 293 ) )
```

The second array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 291 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 291 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idConsultant] => 292 ) )
```

I need a function how will return me, foreach value in the first array the number of occurrence in the second.

The result i am looking for is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [291] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [292] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [293] => 0 ) )
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? post your code also here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a function called [`array_count_values`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) - which is pretty handy in your situation

something like the following should work (assuming your arrays are named `arrA` and `arrB`

```
$arrCntValues = array_count_values(
    array_merge
    (
        array_column($arrA, 'idConsultant'), 
        array_column($arrB, 'idConsultant')
    )
);

print_r($arrCntValues);
```

and if you really need it like your desired structure just iterate over it

```
$arrObjects = [];
foreach($arrCntValues AS $key => $val)
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->$key = $val;
    $arrObjects[] = $obj;
}

print_r($arrObjects);
```